# Gauss elimination in c

Tags: c

I tried to make a program for solving the matrix using gauss elimination, but I don't know, how in line 9. replace "cals" where should be a count of columns but it is local in main.
So, how can I fix it?
Is there any way to put the number of columns in the matrix?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <time.h>


void gauss(double (*matrix)[cals], int cals, int rows)
{
    int x = 1;
    int y = 0;
    int z = 0;

    for(int check = 0; check < rows-1;check++)
    {
        for(int j = x;j<rows;j++)
        {
            if(matrix[j][z] == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
            float help = (matrix[j][z] / matrix[y][z])*-1;
            for(int i = y; i < cals;i++)
            {
                 matrix[j][i] = help*matrix[y][i]+matrix[j][i];
            }
        }

        y++;
        x++;
        z++;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < rows;i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < cals; j++)
        {
            if(matrix[i][j] > 9 || matrix[i][j] < -9)
            {
                printf("%.0f ", matrix[i][j]);
            }
            else
            {
                 printf(" %.0f  ", matrix[i][j]);
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}


int main()
{
    int rows = 3;
    int cals = 3;
        
    srand(time(NULL));

    double matrix[rows][cals];
    for(int i = 0; i < rows;i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0;j < cals;j++)
        {
            matrix[i][j] = rand() %9 + 1;
        }
    }
        
    gauss(matrix, cals, rows);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When using a VLA in a function's arguments, the size(s) needs to come first: `void gauss(int cals, int rows, double matrix[rows][cals])` for example.

Comment: Also be aware beginning with C11, VLAs are a conditional feature that are not required to be supported, e.g. [C11 Standard - 6.7.6.2 Array declarators(p4)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.2p4) *"...Variable length arrays are a conditional feature that implementations need not support."* (language unchanged in C18 standard) Though most compilers will continue to support the feature.

Comment: Marcin Sochacki, curious: why `float help` and not `double help`?

Comment: Thank you so much, I am just a beginner so I didn't know it, I will read about it